# Become the Champion

Tags: code-golf, game

## Tic-Tac-Latin!

#### This is a true story, so names have been altered.

My latin teacher, Mr. Latin, created his own proprietary (no joke) tic tac toe variant. Let's call it tic-tac-latin. The game is simple, it is essentially tic tac toe played on a four by four grid.

## Formal rule declaration

A line is either a row, column or a diagonal. There are two symbols, 'X' and 'O', but one or both may be substituted for a different symbol.

You score one point when you have three of your symbol and one of the other character.

These arrangements score:

```
---O
-O--
XXXO
XOOX

O-XX
-O--
--X-
---O
```

These do not score:

```
----
XXXX
----
OOOO

----
XXX-
----
OOO-
```

The game is won whenever one player has more points then another. The game is a draw only if the board gets filled up.

## Challenge

Solve this game. Your job is to provide a way to guarantee a win or tie, whichever is the optimal result.


Your solution may choose to either start first or second (and may therefore choose it's symbol). It is not mandatory to implement an interactive game where the user inputs moves and the corresponding display changes. It may also **be a function or program which takes input as a game state, and outputs a new board or a description of their move**. Either option must run within approximately ten seconds per move made.

---

Playing your player against any sequence of moves must give the optimal result. This means that you may assume the input position is one that it reachable from play with your player. Submissions must be deterministic, and do not necessarily need to supply a proof of optimality, but if they get cracked (by being beaten) your submissions will be considered invalid (you may leave it up, but add (cracked) in the headline).

---

This is a non-trivial task, so any valid submission is impressive and is worthy of an accepted tick, but I will make code golf the primary winning criterion.

The winner is chosen by going down this list till one winner is chosen.

- Shortest solved implemenation which always wins
- Shortest implementation

Comment: "First the quality of play is looked at" Don't you think it's subjective?

Comment: The task of providing an interface to play seems peripheral of writing a perfect player. I'd suggest simply passing the current game state as input and requiring the code to output a winning move, or even simply an evaluation under perfect play (win, draw, lose).

Comment: A solution can be golfy by doing an inefficient brute force search. Are you OK if the code runs very slowly?

Comment: @zyabin101 I clearly define quality of play it is not a subjective term here

Comment: @xnor I give you the option

Comment: How is this unclear in any way

Comment: @zyabin101 I removed the misleading quality term

Comment: Can we take the game state in a format like a dictionary, or should it be a string? Can we assume we're playing X?

Comment: @xnor I gave a generous ten seconds per move now

Comment: @xnor yes you can choose which side you play and whether or not you move first. Pick a reasonable format.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45826/discussion-between-rohan-jhunjhunwala-and-xnor).

Comment: "*You win the game if you score and in the process do not score for your opponent.*" Does this mean that I can only win when I place a piece, not when my opponent does? What happens if a move creates winning lines for both players: game drawn or play on?

Comment: @RohanJhunjhunwala You should clarify allowed input of the game state, otherwise it's possible that people may take advantage of the currently undefined input format and choose a format that helps their solution a lot.

Comment: You can save 71 bytes by removing items 1 and 3 from the list of criteria

Comment: @MarsUltor any format is alllowed

Comment: @LuisMendo oh ok. Removing them

Comment: @PeterTaylor sorry, your opponent can win it for you.

Comment: @Arnauld yes, that position is unreachable. And was for demonstration purpose only

Comment: Altered to be more clear

Comment: Very good... I would like to know: in minimax function the 2 players have the same code (in the way one maximize positive and the other maximize negative [obtain negative more big])? Or not? Or there are asymmetries? It would be a strange emotion game with a program one wrote that win always who wrote it...

Comment: So the eval function should be: Count all tris with their sign (for example -1 for O and +1 for X) if the result is < 0 than win O and stop the game; if it is >0 than win the X and stop the game; otherwise if it is 0, continue the game. I say that because the eval function not has to end when meets the first tris (in the few I understand)

Comment: @RosLuP yes, i fthat helps you understand

Comment: But one can win in one play (or ply) or in 3 ply or something as that.... Has one to choose the winner move that has less ply? If yes, the board has to be represent at end with 2 number for cell, one can not be sufficient: one if the move win, lost or 0; the other one the deep reachable of that move...

Comment: @RosLuP I'm confused. It is ossible to score to obtainmore scores for both players

Answer (score 6):

## Perl, 147 bytes (non competing, takes more than 10 seconds per move)

Includes +4 for `-0p`

The program plays `X`. It will play a perfect game.

Input the board on STDIN, e.g.:

```
tictaclatin.pl
-X-O
-X--
X-X-
O--O
^D
```

The ouptut will be the same board with all `X` replaced by `O` and vice versa. The empty spots will be filled with a number indicating the result if X would play there, with `1` meaning the result will be a win, `2` a draw and `3` a loss. A finished game just returns the same position with the colors reversed.

In this example the output would be:

```
1O1X
1O33
O3O3
X33X
```

So the position is a win for `X` if he plays in the 3 spots along the top and the left. All other moves lose.

This confusing output is actually convenient if you want to know how the game continues after a move. Since the program always plays `X` you have to swap `X` and `O` to see the moves for `O`. Here for example it's pretty clear that `X` wins by playing in the top left, but what about if `X` plays in the third position along the top ? Just copy the output, put an `O` in place of the move you select and replace all other numbers by `-` again, so here:

```
-OOX
-O--
O-O-
X--X
```

Resulting in:

```
3XXO
3X33
X3X3
O33O
```

Obviously every move by `O` should lose, so how does he lose if he plays in the top left ? Again do this by putting `O` in the top left and replacing the digits by `-`:

```
OXXO
-X--
X-X-
O--O
```

Giving:

```
XOOX
1O33
O3O3
X33X
```

So X has only one way to go for his win:

```
XOOX
OO--
O-O-
X--X
```

Giving

```
OXXO
XX33
X3X3
O33O
```

The situation for `O` remains hopeless. It's easy to see now that every move allows `X` to immediately win. Let's at least try to go for 3 O's in a row:

```
OXXO
XX--
X-X-
O-OO
```

Giving:

```
XOOX
OO13
O3O3
X3XX
```

`X` plays the only winning move (notice that this makes `XXXO` along the third column:

```
XOOX
OOO-
O-O-
X-XX
```

Here the output is:

```
OXXO
XXX-
X-X-
O-OO
```

because the game was already finished. You can see the win on the third column.

The actual program `tictaclatin.pl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -0p
y/XO/OX/,$@=-$@while$|-=/(@{[map{(O.".{$_}O"x3)=~s%O%Z|$`X$'|Z%gr}0,3..5]})(?{$@++})^|$/sx;$@<=>0||s%-%$_="$`O$'";$$_||=2+do$0%eg&&(/1/||/2/-1)
```

Applied to the empty board this evaluates 9506699 positions which takes 30Gb and 41 minutes on my computer. The result is:

```
2222
2222
2222
2222
```

So every starting move draws. So the game is a draw.

The extreme memory usage is mostly caused by the recursion using `do$0`. Using this 154 byte version using a plain function needs 3Gb and 11 minutes:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -0p
sub f{y/XO/OX/,$@=-$@while$|-=/(@{[map{(O.".{$_}O"x3)=~s%O%Z|$`X$'|Z%gr}0,3..5]})(?{$@++})^|$/sx;$@<=>0||s%-%$_="$`O$'";$$_||=2+&f%eeg&&(/1/||/2/-1)}f
```

which is more bearable (but still too much, something must still be leaking memory).

Combining a number of speedups leads to this 160 byte version (5028168 positions, 4 minutes and 800M for the empty board):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -0p
sub f{y/XO/OX/,$@=-$@while$|-=/(@{[map{(O.".{$_}O"x3)=~s%O%Z|$`X$'|Z%gr}0,3..5]})(?{$@++})^|$/osx;$@<=>0||s%-%$_="$`O$'";$a{$_}//=&f+1or return 1%eeg&&/1/-1}f
```

That last one uses `0` for a win (don't confuse with `O`), `1` for a draw and `2` for a loss. The output of this one is also more confusing. It fills in the winning move for X in case of a win without color swap, but if the input game was already won is still does the color swap and does not fill in any move.

All versions of course get faster and use less memory as the board fills up. The faster versions should generate a move in under 10 seconds as soon as 2 or 3 moves have been made.

In principle this 146 byte version should also work:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -0p
y/XO/OX/,$@=-$@while/(@{[map{(O.".{$_}O"x3)=~s%O%Z|$`X$'|Z%gr}0,3..5]})(?{$@++})^/sx,--$|;$@<=>0||s%-%$_="$`O$'";$$_||=2+do$0%eg&&(/1/||/2/-1)
```

but on my machine it triggers a perl bug and dumps core.

All versions will in principle still work if the 6 byte position caching done by `$$_||=` is removed but that uses so much time and memory that it only works for almost filled boards. But in theory at least I have a 140 byte solution.

If you put `$\=` (cost: 3 bytes) just before the `$@<=>0` then each output board will be followed by the status of the whole board: `1` for `X` wins, `0` for draw and `-1` for loss.

Here is an interactive driver based on the fastest version mentioned above. The driver has no logic for when the game is finished so you have to stop yourself. The golfed code knows though. If the suggested move returns with no `-` replaced by anything the game is over.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
sub f{
    if ($p++ % 100000 == 0) {
        local $| = 1;
        print ".";
    }
y/XO/OX/,$@=-$@while$|-=/(@{[map{(O.".{$_}O"x3)=~s%O%Z|$`X$'|Z%gr}0,3..5]})(?{$@++})^|$/osx;$@<=>0||s%-%$_="$`O$'";$a{$_}//=&f+1or return 1%eeg&&/1/-1}

# Driver
my $tomove = "X";
my $move = 0;
@board = ("----\n") x 4;
while (1) {
    print "Current board after move $move ($tomove to move):\n  ABCD\n";
    for my $i (1..4) {
        print "$i $board[$i-1]";
    }
    print "Enter a move like B4, PASS (not a valid move, just for setup) or just press enter to let the program make suggestions\n";
    my $input = <> // exit;
    if ($input eq "\n") {
        $_ = join "", @board;
        tr/OX/XO/ if $tomove eq "O";
        $p = 0;
        $@="";
        %a = ();
        my $start = time();
        my $result = f;
        if ($result == 1) {
            tr/OX/XO/ if $tomove eq "O";
            tr/012/-/;
        } else {
            tr/OX/XO/ if $tomove eq "X";
            tr/012/123/;
        }
        $result = -$result if $tomove eq "O";
        my $period = time() - $start;
        print "\nSuggested moves (evaluated $p positions in $period seconds, predicted result for X: $result):\n$_";
        redo;
    } elsif ($input =~ /^pass$/i) {
        # Do nothing
    } elsif (my ($x, $y) = $input =~ /^([A-D])([1-4])$/) {
        $x = ord($x) - ord("A");
        --$y;
        my $ch = substr($board[$y],$x, 1);
        if ($ch ne "-") {
            print "Position already has $ch. Try again\n";
            redo;
        }
        substr($board[$y],$x, 1) = $tomove;
    } else {
        print "Cannot parse move. Try again\n";
        redo;
    }
    $tomove =~ tr/OX/XO/;
    ++$move;
}
```

Comment: NIce answer. Could you provide some easy way for me to test this? Ideally it would love to see an interactive version... (this is jut for my own curiosity).

Comment: @RohanJhunjhunwala Ok, added a simple interactive driver

Comment: Variable '$move' is not declared
at prog.pl:2

Comment: Is there a heuristic solution a human can implement?

Comment: @RohanJhunjhunwala Just rechecked the driver program. Runs fine, `$move` is declared on line 11. I have no idea if there is a human heuristic. This program just does minimax on the game tree, it doesn't have ***any*** strategic knowledge.

Comment: Huh, ideOne seems borked

Comment: tictaclatin.pl
-X-O
-X--
X-X-
O--O
^D
The next to move is O... It seems that x win in every place one put O...

Comment: @RosLuP `O` to move means you should reverse the colors, so give as input `-O-X -O-- O-O- X--X`. This returns that `O` wins by playing in the top left. This is correct since it defends the diagonal and is a double threat along the top and along the left.

Comment: In linear coordinate 0..15 O in 0, X in 6 (column 3 row 2 beginning to count from 1) than O has to lost for what I see it not win...

Comment: Yes I make one error in encode when it win, I thought it was "xxxo" or "ooox" (3 contiguos symbols the same line and one different; instead it was 3 symbols of one type and one of the other type... Excuse I don't know how cancel above comments from my cellphone... Good morning...

Comment: I would implemented the evaluation function for for tic tac Latin...for the position pl -X-O -X-- X-X- O--O ^D analysis for the O in response result to me the table -1 3 1 3   1 3 11   3 1 3 1     3 1 1 3 were -1 means win O, 3 means occupied, 1 means win X, 0 mean no win

Comment: @RosLuP Yes, that agrees with what my program gives.

Comment: It would result The only win for O, it would be the start one, the 0 coordinate all the other ones are all lost moves for O...

Comment: If number of X is the same numbers of O: than move X; for me begin always X; for you begin O?  it is for this one would not swap X and O

Comment: The number of `X`'s and `O`'s is never used to determine who must move in my program. You ***always*** must give the position with `X` to move. So if it is really `O` to move you ***must*** swap `X` and `O`. So for your example the input to my program is `-O-X -O-- O-O- X--X`. The result `1X3O 3X33 X3X3 O33O`, which  agrees with yours (`1` is win, `3` is loss)

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (ES6) 392 bytes

```
a=>b=>(c="0ed3b56879a4c21f",r=[],k=f=>r.push([a.filter(f),b.filter(f)]),[0,1,2,3].map(i=>k(n=>n%4==i)+k(n=>(n/4|0)==i)),k(n=>n%5==0),k(n=>n&&n-15&&!(n%3)),g=r.find(o=>(o[0].length==1&&o[1].length==2)||(o[0].length==2&&o[1].length==1)),g?parseInt(c[30-[...g[0],...g[1]].map(i=>parseInt(c[i],16)).reduce((p,c)=>p+c)],16):[...a,...b].indexOf(15-a[0])+1?15-a.find(i=>b.indexOf(15-i)==-1):15-a[0])
```

#### Usage

The "bot" will play second.

Draw a 4x4 grid which are numbered like this:

```
+----+----+----+----+
|  0 |  1 |  2 |  3 |
+----+----+----+----+
|  4 |  5 |  6 |  7 |
+----+----+----+----+
|  8 |  9 | 10 | 11 |
+----+----+----+----+
| 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 |
+----+----+----+----+
```

Let's run this in the browser console: Just put `f=` before the code

So, if I wanna start at `1`, I would run `f([1])([])` and it will give me `14`.

Nice move... What if I play `2` afterwards? `f([2,1])([14])`.  It will return `13`.

Lemme try surrendering. Play `3`. `f([3,2,1])([14,13])`.  Oh `0`! You got me!

Play `0`? `f([0,2,1])([14,13])`. `15` Ok let's keep playing...

#### Note

1. Play interactively.  Start with `f([your-step])([])`.
2. Prepend your next step. (See demo above)
3. Help the "bot" input its steps.  It will not give you good results if you give it a random setting. (Like `f([1,2,4])([14,12])` will give `14` - Hey the bot wanted to play on `13` on its second move!

#### Brief Summary

As long as you are not surrendering, the bot will play a mirror move.

Thanks @EHTproductions for telling me that I misread the game rules and golfing tips :P

Now it will also detect if it got checkmate.  If yes, block it!

Its priorities: Block > Mirror > (fallback) look for ways to reproducing a mirror

Comment: I really like the "mirror move" tactic :) I may be misunderstanding, but isn't `3,2,1` for you and `0` for the bot a win for you?

Comment: Oops, I misunderstood as "who captures a pattern of 3 of a kind and 1 of another".  Lemme tweak the solution a bit.. Thanks @ETHproductions.

Comment: A couple of golfing tips: `[0,1,2,3].map(i=>{k(n=>n%4==i);k(n=>Math.floor(n/4)==i);})` can be golfed to `[0,1,2,3].map(i=>k(n=>n%4==i)+k(n=>(n/4|0)==i))`.

Comment: I don't think this is provably winnable

Comment: 0 - 14 - 12 -13 cracks it

Comment: @RohanJhunjhunwala Oh you're right... My answer is only a little bit better than `while(a=prompt())alert(15-a)`... Lemme try thinking of a better strategy other than "smelling for surrender"

Comment: Can this lose? I don't know how to really test this

Comment: Sadly no - Just played with it and a sequence of me playing 0, 11, 14, 3 will create double checkmate. Gotta fix it later...